# Subtract Dates in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I run this query in oracle:

```
  select TO_CHAR(parsed_on, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),  TO_CHAR(creation_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
     (parsed_on -  creation_date) * 1000
        from hotels          
       where TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy') and incoming_psd_id = 608423671;
```

and this is the result, where I was excepting 12 seconds instead of 8.4

[image]

```
10-NOV-2017 07:49:54    10-NOV-2017 07:37:46    8,42592592592
```

Comment: Images are discouraged ..Many of us cannot see the images

Comment: Why are you expecting the subtraction to be 8 seconds? 7:49:54 - 7:37:46 is 12 minutes and 8 seconds. That's 728 seconds. Why are you multiplying by 1000?

Comment: true, sorry !  I was confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct expression for seconds in Oracle would be:

```
(parsed_on -  creation_date) * 24*60*60
```

The difference is decimal days.

If you want minutes, then use:

```
(parsed_on -  creation_date) * 24*60
```

Comment: Then I got 728 seconds, and 07:49:54 - 07:37:46 is more close to 12 seconds

Comment: Take a second look. 7:49 - 7:37 is 12 MINTUES!

Answer (score 0):

```
select ( to_date('10-NOV-2017 07:49:54', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS') - to_date('10-NOV-2017 07:37:46', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS') )* 86400
from dual
```

Correctly gives 728 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to compare dates, you have this option:

```
where trunc(CREATION_DATE) = trunc(SYSDATE)
```

TRUNC cuts out the time portion of dates by default, whereas `trunc(SYSDATE, YYYY)` would cut it down to years only.